# Arduino endless setup expected behavior

Tags: arduino

I am assuming that if the code never leaves the `setup()` all it will just be stuck there forever but (maybe the code doesn't match what I am observing) it seems like something else (rebooting?).
So are there any failsafes that are supposed to trigger in the case of setup stuck in a loop itself?

Comment: Did you write code to hang it in setup?  You write the code. You don’t need something else to tell you of execution will be trapped there.  What’s the actual problem?  What’s the actual code?  Your question is way too vague to diagnose anything as written.  Add details and I’ll take off the downvote.

Comment: If i get your question right, no you will be stuck in the setup()...

Comment: Or are you asking what would happen if you did it on purpose?   In that case the answer is nothing.  There’s no reason setup has to exit.  It’s just a regular function like all the rest.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I am observing some code that should never leave the setup() actually seeming to do that. So there were two options:
1. I am looking at the wrong code (possible)
2. There is a contract in Arduino OS that say that if you don't leave setup in 30secs the board will trigger an interrupt or reboot

Ended up being 1. Someone didn't upload the latest version of the firmware source code.

I couldn't find any official documentation wrt this. Now I know

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what you're asking.  You want to know what happens if you intentionally have your program stay in setup and wonder if that will mess things up.

The thing to understand is that setup and loop are just regular functions like any other.  The real entry point of an Arduino program (or any C or C++ program) is the main() function.  Arduino thought for some reason that it would be helpful to hide this from you and simply give you the setup and loop paradigm.  I guess it is because in most embedded projects on little microcontrollers, the main function is written with an infinite loop at the end running the main program.

Here is the main() function for all of your Arduino programs.  This is what is actually the entry point for your program.

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif
    
    setup();
    
    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see that it first calls the init() and initVariant() functions.  These are functions from the core that set up all the hardware like the timers and input and output registers and stuff.  This is why it's bad to have hardware stuff like a digitalWrite or something in a class constructor, because those could end up being called at global scope and running before these two functions have made the board ready.

Next you see that line with USBDevice.attach(); and that's to handle the USB connection on the boards with native USB controllers like Leonardo.

And finally you see that it calls the setup function once and then calls the loop and serialEventRun functions in an infinite for loop.  I don't 100% understand why the for loop instead of a while(1) loop, but that's how they do it.

So you can see that if your code never gets out of setup then all that happens is that you never get to the point in the program where you call loop.  Nothing else.  It is perfectly acceptable to put a while(1) at the end of setup and stop the controller if you have something you only want to run once.  You can even put that same infinite loop with all the code you would have put in the loop function.  A bit redundant but it wouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: This is true from a functional point of view. The final result can be the same if the execution never gets out of setup(). However, the biggest challenge of embedded software is debug, or add something to the code months later. So best practice is not to do something different without a good reason. I see no reason to create infinite loop in setup() since loop() exists. It can serve a purpose during debug though.